alta latencia con wit.ai
Actualmente uso wit.ai para un voicebot, uso un proveedor para el s2t y wit para analizar ese texto. pero la latencia últimamente es muy alta, entr3 3 y hasta 9 segundos, pero sucede todos los días.
cuento con casi 10.000 utterances. ¿cómo se puede disminuir la latencia?
todos los días sigo entrenando la IA y lo hago en horarios donde no se esté usando.
me he asegurado de que el consumo de la API se haga con la versión más actual
